# Using Group by and Order by together for chat inbox

Tags: mysql

I have tried other answers from stackoverflow but nothing seems to work for me. I have a table name chat(refer image). I want to create inbox page for messages but I am stuck at not being able to display the latest sender's message with id on top. However the following sql statement doesn't work for me:

```
SELECT * from chat where userid='53' group by receiver order by id desc
```

I should be able to see only the latest message and id from latest sender.
Instead I see some random message and order.

The image of table is 
[image: Image of table]

no i want to create inbox with all distinct senders. 
It should be like whatsapp or facebook inbox. I should see the latest messager on the top.

Comment: Can you add the expected result for your snapshot?

Comment: Your problem will be reduced if you use `ORDER BY datetime DESC`? If ok, then use `limit 1`

Comment: Confusion: you say "I should be able to see only the latest message and id from latest sender" (*only one row*), so all here only indicate you to use LIMIT.

Comment: I should be able to see only the latest message and id from latest **senders**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it using `left join`, there are other ways to do the same as well. You may check those too http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

```
select * from chat c1
left join chat c2 on c1.userid = c2.userid
and c1.receiver = c2.receiver
and c1.id < c2.id
where c1.userid = 53 and c2.id is null
order by c1.id desc
```

Comment: Just perfect answer. I wanted this. :)

Answer (score 0):

(edit to explain)

The `limit` clause reduce the number of items in the result. 
See [MySQL guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

```
 [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

The simplest use for retrive 1 row is `limit 1`. To obtain "the last one" you can invert order, try

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM chat 
 WHERE userid='53' 
 GROUP BY receiver 
 ORDER BY datetime 
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: it just displays 1 entry.

Comment: Yes is what you say, you need 1

Comment: no i want to create inbox with all distinct senders. In this case it shows 1 entry from 1 user only.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT` to limit the number of tuples

```
SELECT MAX(id) as mid, message from chat where userid='53' group by receiver
```

Comment: it just displays 1 entry.

Comment: no i want to create inbox with all distinct senders. In this case it shows 1 entry from 1 user only.

Comment: i tried that out it shows distinct messages but not with latest one on the top. but rather shows  first msg on the top